# elfinder invalid backend configuration on my root

Tags: php, ckeditor, elfinder

I'm using elFinder with CKEditor. I have several configuration for opening elFinder using different path. Everything works well, until I use subfolder but not if I try to open the root dir of my site.

in connector.php (wich is in 4 level of sub folders) :

this works well :

```
$opts = array(
        'debug' => false,
        'roots' => array(
            array(
                'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',
                'path'          => '../../../../subdir',
                'URL'           => '/real/path/to/site/www/subdir',
                'accessControl' => 'access'
            )
        )
    );
```

but this doesn't, I get a "invalid backend configuration, readable volumes not available" :

```
$opts = array(
        'debug' => false,
        'roots' => array(
            array(
                'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',
                'path'          => '../../../../',
                'URL'           => '/real/path/to/site/www/',
                'accessControl' => 'access'
            )
        )
    );
```

Permission are Ok on root, I've checked them, they are exactly the same as other subfolder.

Thank's in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the folder "subdir" already exist.

Comment: Well, I would argue this is a potential solution @JosuaMarcelChrisano, OP can tell if it works or not, but I expect the lack of `subdir` folder to cause the kind of errors OP sees.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using a full server path (foo/bar/your/folder) instead of a relative path (../../your/folder).